# Get image from sqlite db and display on page with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, sqlite

I am trying to query my sqlite table to get an image and display it on the page. This is the code I am working with. The weird thing is [0] to [4] doesn't show anything, and [5] and higher returns undefined. My table only has 5 items in it so it looks like the query is working, but it still does not load the items onto the page.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function() {

        var image = <%= Picturebook.where(:book => 'vacation').pluck(:img)[0] %>;
        $('#display_images').append("<img src='" + image + "' >");

    });

</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're doing is a violation of MVC. You should be grabbing the images in your controller:

```
@image = Picturebook.where(:book => 'vacation').pluck(:img)[0]
```

And then in your view:

```
$('#display_images').append("<img src='" + <%= @image %> + "' >");
```

It's considered bad form to query directly from your view, so if you have to get images on the fly, you should consider using AJAX calls to get the src attributes and use a respond_to block in combination with a Javascript file to append the returned images to your view.

If you just need to display the images you can do:
Controller:

```
@images = Picturebook.where(:book => 'vacation')
```

View:

```
<% @images.each do |img| %>
  <%= image_tag(img.src) %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: What's the best way to not display duplicate images?

Comment: You could do @images =  Picturebook.where(:book => 'vacation').map(&:img).uniq

Comment: Cool, that worked, I just had to change `<%= image_tag(img.src) %>` to `<%= image_tag(img) %>`